# Edit content of a list with split and find

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, find

I have a dictionary named `dicitionario1`. I need to replace the content of `dicionario[chave][1]` which is a list, for the list `lista_atributos`. 
`lista_atribtutos` uses the content of `dicionario[chave][1]` to get a list where:

- All the information is separed by `","` except when it finds the characters `"(#"` and `")"`. In this case, it should create a list with the content between those characters (also separated by `","`). It can find one or more entries of '(#' and I need to work with every single of them.

Although this might be easy, I'm stuck with the following code:

```
dicionario1 = {'#998' : [['IFCPROPERTYSET'],["'0siSrBpkjDAOVD99BESZyg',#41,'Geometric Position',$,(#977,#762,#768,#754,#753,#980,#755,#759,#757)"]],
               '#1000' : [['IFCRELDEFINESBYPROPERTIES'],["'1dEWu40Ab8zuK7fuATUuvp',#41,$,$,(#973,#951),#998"]]}



for chave in dicionario1:
    lista_atributos = []
    ini = 0
    for i in dicionario1[chave][1][0][ini:]:
        if i == '(' and dicionario1[chave][1][0][dicionario1[chave][1][0].index(i) + 1] == '#':
            ini = dicionario1[chave][1][0].index(i) + 1
            fim = dicionario1[chave][1][0].index(')')  
            lista_atributos.append(dicionario1[chave][1][0][:ini-2].split(','))
            lista_atributos.append(dicionario1[chave][1][0][ini:fim].split(','))
            lista_atributos.append(dicionario1[chave][1][0][fim+2:].split(','))

            print lista_atributos
```

Result:

```
[["'1dEWu40Ab8zuK7fuATUuvp'", '#41', '$', '$'], ['#973', '#951'], ['#998']]
[["'0siSrBpkjDAOVD99BESZyg'", '#41', "'Geometric Position'", '$'], ['#977', '#762', '#768', '#754', '#753', '#980', '#755', '#759', '#757'], ['']]
```

Unfortunately I can figure out how to iterate over the `dictionario1[chave][1][0]` to get this result:

```
[["'1dEWu40Ab8zuK7fuATUuvp'"], ['#41'], ['$'], ['$'], ['#973', '#951'], ['#998']]
[["'0siSrBpkjDAOVD99BESZyg'", ['#41'], ["'Geometric Position'"], ['$'], ['#977', '#762', '#768', '#754', '#753', '#980', '#755', '#759', '#757']]
```

I need the`"["'1dEWu40Ab8zuK7fuATUuvp'", '#41', '$', '$']..."` in the result, also to turn into `["'1dEWu40Ab8zuK7fuATUuvp'"], ['#41'], ['$'], ['$']...`

Also If I modify `"Geometric Position"` to `"(Geometric Position)"` the result becomes:

```
[["'1dEWu40Ab8zuK7fuATUuvp'", '#41', '$', '$'], ['#973', '#951'], ['#998']]
```

SOLUTION: (thanks to Rob Watts)

```
import re

dicionario1 =["'0siSrBpkjDAOVD99BESZyg',#41,'(Geometric) (Position)',$,(#977,#762,#768,#754,#753,#980,#755,#759,#757)"]

dicionario1 =  re.findall('\([^)]*\)|[^,]+', dicionario1[0])

for i in range(len(dicionario1)):
    if dicionario1[i].startswith('(#'):
        dicionario1[i] = dicionario1[i][1:-1].split(',')
    else:
        pass

print dicionario1

["'0siSrBpkjDAOVD99BESZyg'", '#41', "'(Geometric) (Position)'", '$', ['#977', '#762', '#768', '#754', '#753', '#980', '#755', '#759', '#757']]
```

Comment: Why does `[['1', '2']]` get split into `[['1'], ['2']]` but `[['2.1', '2.2', '2.3']]` doesn't get split?

Comment: this is just an example, the real code doesnt actually take the numbers showed. a real example would be:

#982 : [[IFCPROPERTYSET],["'2ox2xoAH983wkyoGwQ_TXa',#41,'Structural',$,(#769,#761,#269,#770,#274,#272,#275,#981))"]

Comment: if your example code doesn't have the same properties as your real code, how are we to help create a solution? What are the criteria that makes one list element get split while another doesn't?

Comment: I edited it to be more simple to read the dict. I'll edit my post to be more objective.

Comment: Will you have strings with commas in them? For example `["'has,commas,','other_stuff']`

Comment: @RobWatts: Yes that is possible, I edited the post. Please look at `(3)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see with your code is the use of `index`:

```
ini = dicionario1[chave][1][0].index(i) + 2
fim = dicionario1[chave][1][0].index(')')
```

`index` returns the index of the *first* occurrence of the character. So if you have two `(`'s in your string, then both times it will give you the index of the first one. That (and your `break` statement) is why in your example you've got `['2.1', '2.2', '2.3']` correctly but also have `'(#5.1', '5.2', '5.3)'`.

You can get around this by specifying a starting index to the `index` method, but I'd suggest a different strategy. If you don't have any commas in the parsed strings, you can use a fairly simple regex to find all your groups:

```
'\([^)]*\)|[^,]+'
```

This will find everything inside parenthesis and also everything that doesn't contain a comma. For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> teststr = "'1',$,#41,(#10,#5)"
>>> re.findall('\([^)]*\)|[^,]+', teststr)
["'1'", '$', '#41', '(#10,#5)']
```

This leaves you will everything grouped appropriately. You still have to do a little bit of processing on each entry, but it should be fairly straightforward.

During your processing, the `startswith` method should be helpful. For example:

```
>>> '(something)'.startswith('(')
True
>>> '(something)'.startswith('(#')
False
>>> '(#1,#2,#3)'.startswith('(#')
True
```

This will make it easy for you to distinguish between `(...)` and `(#...)`. If there are commas in the `(...)`, you could always split on comma after you've used the regex.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is that I only want to modify the entries with `'(# ... )'` and not `'( ... )'`.

Comment: @JoaoSa I added some info about how to tell them apart.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll give it a try. Still today, I will give you some feedback. My knowledge about Python is very basic but I'm trying to use it to build my thesis. Thank you again.